# Does anyone know the OEM for the 2006 Infiniti qx56 oxygen sensors

Tags: nissan, o2-sensor, emissions, infiniti

I've got the part numbers and some cross references for the 2006 Infiniti QX56 oxygen sensors, but I would like to buy from the OEM. Bosch? Denso?

```
infiniti front left/right 226937S000 bosch 17204 5 wire
infiniti rear  left       226A07S001 bosch 16596 4 wire 
infiniti rear  right      226A08U300 bosch 16513 4 wire
```

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!